# APIController для парковки

Tags: java, сервер

мне нужно написать APIController с вот таким ТЗ: 
Есть парковка на 20 мест.
Необходимо реализовать методы:
/park (POST-запрос) - припарковать машину на любое свободное место
/unpark (POST-запрос) - убрать с парковки машину на определенном парковочном месте
/free (GET-запрос) - показать список свободных парковочных мест

Я предположил, что мне нужно создать скажем массив/коллекцию на 20 чисел и если скажем я припарковал машину, то удалять из массива номер этого парковочного  места, но я не понимаю как это всё это реализовать. Задание вроде не сложное как сказали, но я что-то не могу сообразить, что где написать
Не могли бы вы мне подсказать примерную структуру/алгоритм как должен выглядеть мой APIController?
Надо ли мне создавать дополнительный классы, либо это задание можно целиком выполнить в классе APIController?

Comment: Среди классов должна быть модель (Парковка - коллекция, лучше мапа наверное, класс Автомобиль, если нужно сохранять детали авто, а не только есть/нет на парковке). Еще неплохо было бы это все делать в сервисах, а не тупо в самом контроллере. Плюс неизвестно, надо ли это все хозяйство хранить в БД или достаточно памяти...

Comment: В БД хранить не надо, а с сервисами полагаю пока я не работал,)

Comment: Ольга, ты правильно предположил )))), что нужно создать коллекцию с пронумерованными парко-местами. Но вместо удаления номера, я бы добавлял/убирал признак (например, номер авто) в соответствующую ячейку.

Comment: (например, номер авто) - это имеется ввиду гос знак?

Я создал модель - класс Parking, в нём я создаю коллекцию потом?

А как мне допустим потом обращаться к этой коллекции с APIControllera?

Comment: Да, гос номер, но я так понял, вам надо просто добавлять на свободное место, а перед тем как удалять, проверять - есть там авто или нет. Т.е., достаточно коллекции, которая хранит `Boolean`. Ну и этот класс `Parking` с коллекцией внутри вы создаете и инициализируете в вашем контроллере.

Comment: Вообщем, каким то образом я написал код который заполняет паковочные места при выполнение команды в Postman /park и показывает после этого свободные оставшиеся номера мест при исполнении  команды /free
Но теперь стоит самая сложная задача, как мне принимать число с Postamana (получается клиент желает убрать свою машину с парковки и должен сделать запрос /unpark с номером конкретного паковочного места), как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122318/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-apicontroller-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81-postman

Вот здесь я пересоздал вопрос, более наглядно с кодом