# Паркую машины в APIController, как принять число с Postman?

Tags: java, алгоритм, spring, сервер, postman

Господа, помогите пожалуйста
Передо мной такая вот задачка 
Есть парковка на 20 мест.
Необходимо реализовать методы:
/park (POST-запрос) - припарковать машину на любое свободное место
/unpark (POST-запрос) - убрать с парковки машину на определенном паковочном месте
/free (GET-запрос) - показать список свободных паковочных мест

Я сделал методы /park и /free, но метод /unpark не понимаю как сделать
/unpark должен убирать машину с **конкретного** паковочного места, а значит я должен в Postman сделать запрос с конкретным номером паковочного места и потом с этим числом ещё работать в методе
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне сделать такого что бы сделать запрос в Postman /unpark ***2*** - например и потом я мог работать с этой двойкой в классе Parking?

@RestController
public class APIController {

```
Parking parkovka = new Parking();

@PostMapping("/free")
public String free(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    //for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    //  list.add(i);
    //}
    return "Свободные парковочные места под номерами " + parkovka.free1();
}

@PostMapping("/park")
public String park() {
    return "Машина припаркована на месте № " + parkovka.park1();
}

@PostMapping("/news/{id}")
public String news(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id) {
    parkovka.unpark();
    return "News [" + id + "]";
```

public class Parking {

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
//public static ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
public static APIController counted = new APIController();


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Parking.unpark());

}

public static ArrayList free1() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
     int count = 0; // Счетчик занятых мест
     // Цикл добавляющий 20 мест на парковку
        if (list.size() < 20) { 
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                list.add(i);
                list2.add(i);
            }
        }
        //Цикл свободных мест на парковке
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (list.get(i) != 100) {
                list2.add(list.get(i));
                count++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("count = " +  count );
        int freePlaces = list.size();
        return list2;
}

public static int park1() {
    free1();
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (list.get(count) != 100) {
            list.set(count, 100);
            break;
        } else if (list.get(count) == 100) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static Integer unpark() {
    return 5;
}
```

}

Comment: Только сейчас заметил что у вас нет главного класса Spring, попробуйте сгенерировать проект в [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/)

Comment: Ой, как всё сложно... Заметьте, что 20 в данном случае - это не размер `size()` вашего листа, а размер внутреннего массива, который будет потом увеличиваться при необходимости. Ну и как уже ответили, `@PathVariable` для метода `Post` не годится.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, но мы пока ещё не использовали написание API с использование главного класса Spring поэтому я сделал без него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все весьма просто, если вы используете Spring (судя по аннотациям, да). Можете воспользоватся такими аннотациями как @RequestBody:

```
@PostMapping("/park")
public ResponseEntity park(@RequestBody ParkingPlace parkingPlace) {
    parkingService.park(parkingPlace.getParkingPlaceNumber());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

в данном примере ParkingPlace это POJO класс с атрибутом `Integer parkingPlaceNumber`.

Для примера выше в постмане нужно будет указать [Body] -> raw и JSON (если используете spring-boot-starter-json)

Так же можно использовать `@RequestParam`, тогда пример будет следующим

```
@PostMapping("/park")
public ResponseEntity park(@RequestParam(name = "place") Integer parkingPlaceNumber) {
    parkingService.park(parkingPlaceNumber);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

В постмане тогда указать [Body] -> raw `place=1`